# Close Opened Hibernation sessions if exist

Tags: java, hibernate, swing

When a Hibernate session is opened (`sessionFactory.openSession()`) it might be closed. It is ok. In case it is missed to close an opened session which is used to retrieve data (not to save or update or delete) any where in the application, how to close opened sessions if exists?

(Let's say when a `JFrame` is closed, if there are opened sessions available, they must be closed. Closing sessions can be done by going through the codes one by one, but I mean here, without checking codes, is there any way to close sessions which are missed to close with some piece of code).

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you close the session when your database operation finished?
I mean, In DAO classes you get opened session perform database operation. And in finally block, Close your session.
You can close session like :

```
finally {
   if(session!=null){
      session.close();
   }
}
```

OR

You can get the current session using

```
Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

And close session on closing event of JFrame.

I get following lines from [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html)

> The main contract here is the creation of Session instances. Usually
>   an application has a single SessionFactory instance and threads
>   servicing client requests obtain Session instances from this factory.
>   The internal state of a SessionFactory is immutable. Once it is
>   created this internal state is set. This internal state includes all
>   of the metadata about Object/Relational Mapping.
>   Implementors must be threadsafe.

And it is our duty to close session when finished the operation or transaction. When we close sessionfactory all resources(connection pools etc) are released properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.I mean, in case closing the session is forgotten as a mistake and when the application runs then more opened sessions exist and then memory wastage may occur. In such a case, how to close or see that there any session is opened?

Comment: can you give example of such scenario (I cant visualize)?

Comment: `Session s=sessionFactory.openSession(); List list=s.createCritaria... .list();`  if this session 's' is forgotten to close.(there is no code: s.close(); )  lets say, this getting list is executed more times and then a new session is opened.Then every time above code is executed,a new session begins,but not closed.then more and more open sessions may exists.Finally it may a cause to be jvm memory overloaded.isn't it? I want to close opened sesseions if exist. Thank you for your attention

Comment: So Aash, I have edited above answer accordingly. As we have single Sessionfactory for application, we'll have all sessions associated with application and we can close them. I am not sure but I read and made conclusion.

Comment: Thanks.I tried to close the session which is taken from `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();`.then there was an exception saying no session open.But there was already opened a session which was not closed. I suppose we d better to go through our codes twice checking opened sessions.