# No Hibernate session bound to the thread while using multiple transation managers

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, sessionfactory, transactionmanager

I have created two transaction managers(one for READ requests and another for READ-WRITE requests) and two session factories for the same.

Important snippets are as follows:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="txManagerRead"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    <qualifier value="READ"/>
</bean>

<bean id="txManagerWrite"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory1" />
     <qualifier value="WRITE"/>
</bean>

<bean id="AbstractSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    abstract="true">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
.....
....
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="SessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    parent="AbstractSessionFactory">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
.........
.........
</props>
</property>
</bean>



<bean id="SessionFactory1"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    parent="AbstractSessionFactory">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
.........
.........
</props>
</property>
</bean>
```

I am getting following exception :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)

    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:574)

    at com.amazon.im.dao.hibernate.GenericDAOImpl.getSession(GenericDAOImpl.java:53)

    at com.amazon.im.dao.hibernate.CategoryDAOImpl.findAllActiveCategories(CategoryDAOImpl.java:54)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Method which calls DAO is as follows:

```
 @Transactional(rollbackFor = { DependencyException.class, ServiceException.class }, readOnly = true, value="READ")
@Operation("getActiveCategories")
public GetActiveCategoriesResponse getActiveCategories() throws ServiceException, DependencyException
{ .....
......
......
}
```

Can anyone point me to the part I am doing wrong?

Comment: I completely fail to see the point of doing this? Why have 2 (and even 3) different TMs? What happens if a read-write method wants to call a read method?

Comment: @JB: As of now, assume that read-write method will call write method only.
Reason of having 2 TMs (3rd one is default one) is presence of Transactional annotation for each API which creates a session in the start, that is used for subsequent DAO calls.

Comment: I understand that. But what do you gain over 1 single TM used for all operations except needless complexity? The standard way of doing is to have one TM. No need for several.

Comment: We don't want to use ThreadLocal variables as explained here - http://blog.springsource.org/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing.
Is there any better approach?

Comment: @tyro I am using CustomRoutingDataSource in my app and I didn't prefer using ThreadLocal variable and setting the CustomRoutingDataSource every time and hence I made it a session bean . Other than this , You could go for programmatic Txn management.

Comment: @JBNizet Could you please tell me the way to do this with single TM without using ThreadLocal? Would be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using @Transactional("Tx_Manager_Name") as per [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional) . Your configuration seems to be correct since multiple Txn managers are supported through Qualifiers as well .

Comment: Thanks Aravind. But, I think this code is doing exactly what you said. @Transactional(rollbackFor = { DependencyException.class, ServiceException.class }, readOnly = true, value="READ"). Let me know if there is any difference. "READ" is the name of TX_MANAGER.

Comment: @tyro - I have duplicated your entire configuration and did not find any issue . I suspect that there may be an issue in the Dao layer - Injection of session factory or something . Or maybe you are performing a lookup outside the transaction.

Comment: Yes. I made a blunder :( <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />  was commented.
Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration is wrong. Hibernate and even spring allows you to create only one session factory per app. Check out this link : [Spring + Hibernate session lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724259/spring-hibernate-session-lifecycle/8725259#8725259). You can create session per transaction.

Also check this link : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html

Comment: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one(sessionfactory) here

Comment: not sure if that is correct.  I have built several applications that use multiple session factories, one per `dataSource`.  Of course, under the hood, Hibernate might be reusing the same `SessionFactory` to create new sessions (like what EhCache does with `CacheManager` and caches).

Comment: Yeah! that can be. If you are using multiple dataSource, you can create sessionfactory per dataSource. But @tyro is using single dataSource for two(read and write) sessionFactories, and that is not possible.