# how spring manage hibernate session lifecycle

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, lifecycle

Spring is used in our team's Java EE project, and hibernate is used for underlying ORM.

transactionManager is set like below:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

sessionFactory is set like below:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="packagesToScan"
value="com.company.model" />
<property name="hibernateProperties">

<value>
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=50
</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

my quesiton is thoughtout the whole setting, I didn't see any property setting for hibernate session lifecycle.In hibernate reference, Contextual sessions was introduced and it's said that there three implementations of CurrentSessionContext.

1. JTA 2.Thread 3.Managed

How do I know which implementation has been used.Maybe by Spring, but I've no idea.

Comment: check here similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724259/spring-hibernate-session-lifecycle

Comment: I've read the post you suggested, but still didn't get the exact answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SessionFactory is created by Spring using given dataSource and is taking its DB connections from connection pool. We get a Hibernate session via SessionFactory.getCurrentSession(). then start transaction, do the work and then commit() or rollback(), and at the end close the connection(connection object will be returned to the pool). Hibernate session factory will be destroyed/closed when we either stop application or shutdown the server. And By default, Thread implementations of CurrentSessionContext will be used, if you use HibernateTransactionManager. If you want to use, jta implementation: you have to use "JtaTransactionManager" as a Transaction manager.

Comment: That's cool, one question is that you said "And By default, Thread implementations of CurrentSessionContext will be used, if you use HibernateTransactionManager." But How can I get that from offical docs?

Answer (score 0):

The `hibernate.current_session_context_class` configuration parameter defines which `org.hibernate.context.CurrentSessionContext` implementation should be used. For backwards compatibility, if this configuration parameter is not set but a `org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookup` is configured, Hibernate will use the `org.hibernate.context.JTASessionContext.`, which you can also configure by setting the property and using the shortform as 'jpa'.

So by default, you are using 'jpa' - you can override it by defining a property like.

```
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">managed</prop>
```

Read this for complete information on contextual sessions.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session