# Hibernate : Where exactly do we need to close the SessionFactory Object

Tags: hibernate, sessionfactory

I am using Hibernate 3 version for my Application .

While going through tutorials on Hibernate, I found out that, `SessionFactory` should be created only once for the application.
So for this I have decided to use a static block inside a class and a static method to return this as shown.

```
public class SessionFactoryInitiliaztion {
    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Where exactly do I need to close this `sessionFactory` object , so that it resales the memory ?

Comment: You can take Spring into consideration. Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724259/spring-hibernate-session-lifecycle on session management with Spring and Hibernate.

Comment: Probably as long as the application is running else at exit. Can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4544053/366964 for more details.

Comment: Thanks , but i am not using Spring for this Application , its based on Servlets , JSP and Hibernate and MYSQL .

Comment: With servlets, you best bet IMHO is to use a servlet context listener (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to open the SessionFactory at app start time and close the SessionFactory at app shut down time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot think of any reason (offhand) why you would want to close the session factory while your application exists, so I wouldn't be too concerned about reclaiming the memory. I would just close it when your application is shutting down.

Comment: You have misunderstood my question , i want to close it when the application exists , so can i do this inside servlet  destroy method or is there any appropriate place for closing the Hibernate sessionFactory Object ?? .

Comment: sorry, yes that is where you should close it, in destroy()

Comment: Well doing it in a servlet destroy method assumes you have just a single servlet and it is not pooled.  The better option is to use ServletContextListener

Comment: Yeah your right, I shouldn't have assumed that that was how this was set up.

Answer (score 0):

This appears a bug, however with a "deprecated" configuration the sessionFactory closes correctly:

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```